# Is Lord Brahma described as 4 faced in the Vedas?

Tags: vedas, brahma, shruti

In the Puranas we have several references for Brahma having four faces -

Ex - [ŚB 9.1.9](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/9/1/9/)

Is there any reference of Lord Brahma having 4 heads in the Vedas?

Is it a later added part in the puranas?

Please provide proper scriptural reference.